# Triangle Inequality considering Inverse Operator

Tags: operator-theory, inverse

Let $E,F$ be two normed spaces and $T,S \in L(E,F)$ be invertable and also let  $(T+S)$ be boundedly invertable. Can we assume that $||(T+S)^{-1}|| \le ||T^{-1}|| + ||S^{-1}||$ holds?

Comment: Is there not a theorem that states that $\| T^{-1} \| = \frac{1}{\|T\|}$? If this is true then this would not be the case.

Comment: $T+S$ invertible don't implies $T$ ou $S$ invertible. Take the operators $E_{11}$ and $E_{22}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose the matrices are $e_{11}$ and $e_{22}$. We have $E_{11}+E_{22}=I$ is invertible, but $E_{11}$ and $E_{22}$ is not invertible.

Comment: Do you consider $T$ and $S$ invertibles?

Comment: @M.Lobo Sorry I do of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just solved my own query in the comments: The relation we have for all bounded, invertible operators in general is that $\|T^{-1}\| \geq \frac{1}{\| T\|}$. This being the case we have

$$\|(T+S)^{-1}\| \geq \frac{1}{\| T +S\|} \geq \frac{1}{\|T \| + \|S\|}$$

and this is probably as much as we could say about it without more information about specific operators. You may be able to manipulate this into some you could use, however, I'm certain the statement in your question doesn't hold in general.

Consider the multiplication operators $(\mathbb{I}f)(x) = f(x)$ and $(-\frac{3}{2}\mathbb{I}f)(x) = -\frac{3}{2}f(x)$ for all functions $f$ in the space. Then these operators are bounded and invertible, hence looking to the left hand side of your proposed inequality we have

$$\| (\mathbb{I} - \frac{3}{2}\mathbb{I})^{-1}\| = \|(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{I})^{-1}\| = \|-2\mathbb{I}\| = 2.$$

Similarly for the right hand side:

$$\|(\mathbb{I})^{-1}\| + \|(-\frac{3}{2}\mathbb{I})^{-1}\| = \|\mathbb{I}\| + \|-\frac{2}{3}\mathbb{I} \| = 1 + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{5}{3}.$$

Hence we can see that LHS$>$RHS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope that you understand that I can only accept a answer as 'solution' if prove or disprove is given.

Comment: I refer you to my counter example. Hopefully I haven't missed anything!

Comment: @CharleyScotford, $1<3/2$. This is not a counterexample.

Comment: I've made an edit so it actually makes sense now.

Comment: @CharleyScotford, Now seems correct.